# Capture series of bitmapdata from videodisplay

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

Short of recording a video, I wanted to save a bunch of frames from videodisplay. I know how to grab a photo from videodisplay but Im more concerned of How to grab a series of bitmapdata objects to form a small video clip. I can do a loop and capture a bunch of bitmapdata but is this the correct way is there a better way? Im afraid I might lock the app to a halt. Im not really interested on recording an flv.

Comment: If the length isn't large, a Vector.<BitmapData> you use to store to then copyPixels() into a single render BitmapData should work fine. You can also have a look at Thibault Imbert's [AS3 GIF Encoder](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=93). Regarding halts, depending on your target player, you might want to look into [AS3 Workers](http://esdot.ca/site/2012/intro-to-as3-workers-part-2-image-processing) to thread things a bit.

Comment: thanks on the heads up on vector. I also read it on Thibault's blog that the Vector allowed him to optimize jpgencoder (much faster than sdk default), although im using alchemy'd encoder. anyway I found my answer by reading the code of FLVRecorder (code.google), all w/o the use of as3 worker. I'll explore it on some other day as the doubled memory usage is not to attractive right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found some answers by reading code of FLVRecorder (code.google)